# VB.NET - Timer - Run continuous process on the server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Tools : VB.net (asp) in Visual Studio 2013, MySQL 5.x

I've a process that does the following :
1. Read one/two tables from the database. 
2. Create a XML.
3. Send\ the XML to a third party server. And gets the response. 
4. Saves few attributes my database.

The process is working fine.

Now, I want to run this after every 15 minutes. And that's where I need your help/guidance.

In theory, I can write a small Timer based program that runs either on server or client side which will do steps 1 through 4. However, what I need is :
1. The process should run independent of someone is browsing the page.  I mean, let's say I start the timer and process starts running after every 15 minutes. Now, if I closed the browser, I need this process to be running even if I close the browser. 
2. If I've triggered the timer, watched the process for say 1 hour then I closed the browser. A colleague of mine, after some time logged on and he should see the continuous progress. He even want to stop the process.
3. The interval of 15 minutes if configurable and run the process on adhoc basis - but I think i'll sort this out.

In short, it is a sort of controlling a background process.

Appreciate if you hint me on  how to approach on point 1 and 2 above. In theory, I do not require a code, just a guidance will do but I would be happy just in case you it, or a good link for that matter. :) Afterwall, who hates spoon feeding ? :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, all of your process are working in ASP VB .NET?

Comment: You are looking for a [Windows Service](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/window_service11262005045007AM/window_service.aspx)

Comment: Or create an exe to do this and run it every 15 mins using windows task scheduler

Comment: Okay. Yes all are in asp.net

Comment: SignalR is your way to go